# Projection and View Matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

## Edit

I have determined it's not a problem with my matrices, rather `glGetUniformLocation` not finding the requested variable

## Edit 2

I've fixed the above mistake and unit matrices now work. So the error goes back to my matrices now I think.

---

I am having some issues getting my projection and view matrices correct. I have checked them against several examples and don't know where I am going wrong. I see nothing on screen unless I disable the shader.

I calculate the model matrix like so:

```
float aspect = (float)width / std::max(1.0f, (float)height);
float top = tan(Maths::toRadian(FOV * 0.5f)) * near;
float bottom = -top;
float right = top * aspect;
float left = -right;

projMatrix.reset();
projMatrix(0, 0) = (2.0f * near) / (right - left);
projMatrix(1, 1) = (2.0f * near) / (top - bottom);
projMatrix(2, 2) = -(far + near) / (far - near);
projMatrix(2, 3) = -1.0f;
projMatrix(3, 2) = (-2.0f * far * near) / (far - near);
projMatrix(3, 3) = 0.0f;
```

I calculate the view matrix like so:

```
Camera::Camera(const Maths::Vector3& pos)
    : position(pos), target(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) {
    target.normalize();
    up.normalize();
}

Maths::Matrix4 Camera::getMatrix() const {
    Maths::Matrix4 mat;
    Maths::Vector3 z = position - target;
    Maths::Vector3 x = Maths::crossProduct(up, z);
    Maths::Vector3 y = Maths::crossProduct(z, x);

    z.normalize();
    x.normalize();

    mat(0, 0) = x.x; mat(0, 1) = y.x; mat(0, 2) = y.z;
    mat(1, 0) = x.y; mat(1, 1) = y.y; mat(1, 2) = y.z;
    mat(2, 0) = x.z; mat(1, 2) = y.z; mat(2, 2) = y.z;

    mat(3, 0) = -Maths::dotProduct(x, position);
    mat(3, 1) = -Maths::dotProduct(y, position);
    mat(3, 2) = -Maths::dotProduct(z, position);

    return mat;
}
```

Then I pass them into the shader eventually like so:

```
glGetUniformLocation(viewMatrix, "view");
glGetUniformLocation(projMatrix, "proj");

glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrix, 1, GL_TRUE, view.asArray());
glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrix, 1, GL_TRUE, proj.asArray());
```

and finally my shader:

Vertex:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
};
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

And to cover all bases here are my methods for calculating the dot product and the cross product:

```
float dotProduct(const Vector3& a, const Vector3& b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

Vector3 crossProduct(const Vector3& a, const Vector3& b) {
    return Vector3(a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y,
                   a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z,
                   a.x * b.y - a.y * b.z);
}
```

Comment: Is this on purpose you aren't using the glm library?

Comment: Are you actually drawing anything?  Some sort of triangle or some other model?  I assume you editted that out, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I draw a triangle but it only shows if I disable the shader.

@Need4Sleep It's been a while since I have done this sort of maths so I wanted to remind myself of it all. Making my own implementation forces me to relearn it. I would use GLM if I understood everything already, if this wasn't for learning or if I had the discipline to read articles without the small reward of "hey it works" at the end.

Comment: @lerp understood if this is just from a math perspective, but from a programming perspective the math is arbitrary, you don't NEED to know the math behind these matrices for the most part. All of this is replaced with two functions, `glm::lookat()` and `glm::perspective()`

Comment: @Need4Sleep I know I don't NEED to know the math, but I WANT to know the math :) Is GLM open-source? I will look at it and make a comparison if so.

Comment: have you tried drawing a triangle with active shaders, but with identity matrices passed in as projection & view? imo you should rule out an error in your shader / vertex attrib / uniform setup first, the potential for a mistake is quite big there. ( and I don't see an obvious mistake in you matrix code either  ) Other than that, you could try downloading glm, feeding the same values that you use for rendering to their lookAt / perspective functions and then print out & compare the results to yours - that would at least clear up the question of whether your calculations are correct immediately

Comment: @user2253160 Aha, I passed in unit matrices and I have the same problem!

Comment: @genpfault Ahh, it's row major. Okay I made them column major and it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo! My view matrix was wrong. Notice how I was setting the last column all to `y.z`...

Here's my amended view matrix:

```
Maths::Matrix4 mat;
Maths::Vector3 z = Maths::normalize(target - position);
Maths::Vector3 x = Maths::normalize(Maths::crossProduct(z, up));
Maths::Vector3 y = Maths::crossProduct(x, z);

mat(0, 0) = x.x; mat(0, 1) = y.x; mat(0, 2) = -z.x;
mat(1, 0) = x.y; mat(1, 1) = y.y; mat(1, 2) = -z.y;
mat(2, 0) = x.z; mat(1, 2) = y.z; mat(2, 2) = -z.z;

mat(3, 0) = -Maths::dotProduct(x, position);
mat(3, 1) = -Maths::dotProduct(y, position);
mat(3, 2) = Maths::dotProduct(z, position);
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Looking at your source I noticed something, you're voxel.draw() function is called after you disable your attrib array, meaning nothing is being sent to your shader when you call the function. If i'm not mistaken, it should be this:

```
void Engine::draw() {
    light.enable();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); disable attrib array before calling draw?

    voxel.draw();
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); //NOW disable it, so your draw function works!
}
```

Another note: I know you don't want to use glm, but i **HIGHLY** recommend using it. Here is your entire chunk of code using glm:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
//projection matrix
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
//camera matrix
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(4,3,3),   //camera is at (4,3,3) in world
    glm::vec3(0,0,0),   //look at origin
    glm::vec3(0,1,0)    //head up
);
```

Comment: It doesn't use a 2D array, it uses a 1D array and it does return the reference to the first element. Could it be a problem using a 1D array?

Comment: @lerp try not to transpose your array, set your value to `GL_FALSE` and re-compile from there.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I tried passing unit matrices to the shader and I have the same problem so there's either a problem somewhere between the code and the shader.

Comment: @lerp Could you send me your source? I'll play around with it and see if I can find the bug through guess and check

Comment: I'm close to fixing it. I've fixed the unit matrices not working. (I was trying to access the uniform variables before linking). So now it's back to me calculating the matrices incorrectly? I will put the code on github, give me a few min :)

Comment: @lerp updated, I think I found something in your engine code.

Comment: Still no luck. I added in the triangle part to debug because that draw function wasn't working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30022/discussion-between-need4sleep-and-lerp)